# My jupyter notebook is empty when launched?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am unable to see any of my files when I launch Jupyter from the terminal, locally?

Any idea what could be the issue here?

I tried updating it to the lastest version however nothing works.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42CPS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1L4p.png)

Comment: Have you tried restarting everything, even your computer, since you updated it? The first screenshot you show is possibly characteristic of not doing that. However, if you did then it may mean you have an incomplete installation. One suggestion other than finding all involved files and purging everything before you try reinstalling, would be to install and use [the Anaconda Distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/index.html) & use the Anaconda Navigator to launch Jupyter.

Comment: I should have added to the causes of that behavior would be incomplete clearing out of previous files from older versions and/or conflicts with files also in your system's path.

Comment: I managed to run using Anaconda, that was really helpful. Thank you